# div popup over two frames

Tags: javascript, html, frameset

i have two frames(Html frameset) in one window like left frame and right frame i want to show one div popup over two frames from one frame it is working in IE using `window.createpopup` but in mozilla it is not working can any one help me?

NOTE: i am using div as a tool tip.

Comment: window.open to create a popup

Answer (score 3):

`createPopup` is a Microsoft-only thing.

If you need it to be across two frames, it will have to be its own window, and so you'll need `window.open` ([MDC link](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.open), [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Note that in modern browsers, you can only successfully call `window.open` to create a popup in direct response to a user action such as a click, otherwise the browser will silently suppress the window.